# How to permanently remove all NAs?

Tags: r, imputation

I am imputing missing variables. The function seems to work at first:

```
# Replace NA with "None"

vars_to_none = c("Alley", "BsmtQual", "BsmtCond", "BsmtExposure", "BsmtFinType1", "BsmtFinSF1", "BsmtFinType2", "FireplaceQu", "GarageType", "GarageYrBlt", "GarageFinish", "GarageQual", "GarageCond", "PoolQC", "Fence", "MiscFeature", "MasVnrType")

sapply(combi %>% select(vars_to_none), function(x) x = ifelse(is.na(x), "None", x))
```

Output: a dataframe with "None" in formerly NA spots. Here's a portion of the output.

Alley  BsmtQual BsmtCond BsmtExposure BsmtFinType1 BsmtFinSF1 BsmtFinType2

```
[1,] "None" "Gd"     "TA"     "No"         "GLQ"        "706"      "Unf"       
[2,] "None" "Gd"     "TA"     "Gd"         "ALQ"        "978"      "Unf"       
[3,] "None" "Gd"     "TA"     "Mn"         "GLQ"        "486"      "Unf"       
[4,] "None" "TA"     "Gd"     "No"         "ALQ"        "216"      "Unf"
```

So good so far.

But when I check for NA's again...

```
which(is.na(combi$Alley))
```

...I get 2000+ entries. head() shows the same thing:

```
head(combi$Alley)
```

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

I tried saving the sapply function to combi, which caused an error I'm not familiar with.

```
combi <- sapply(combi %>% select(vars_to_none), function(x) x = ifelse(is.na(x), "None", x))
head(combi$Alley)
```

Error in combi$Alley : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
> which(is.na(combi$Alley))
```

Error in combi$Alley : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

How can I get the combi dataframe to permanently hold the replacement of NA's with "None"?

Comment: Appears you are trying to replace values within `combi`. But with `combi <- ...`, you are replacing all of `combi` with only part of `combi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first effort at code you offered does not have an assignment back to `combi`, so `combi` will be unaffected by those calculations.

Need to do:

```
combi[vars_to_non] <- sapply(combi %>% select(vars_to_none), 
                              function(x) x = ifelse(is.na(x), "None", x))
```

I would have not used the tidyverse-base mixture of code, so would have answered:

```
combi[vars_to_non] <- lapply( combi[vars_to_non] , 
                              function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- "None"; x}
```

I'm not sure whether the result would be different but I suspect my version is more efficient, because it doesn't require building multiple vectors the length of the of the x column.

The second effort failed because the default value from sapply is a matrix and you replaced all of combi with a matrix-ified version of just the columns that you modified. Matrices in R are just atomic vectors with dimenstions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification @42- those both worked! And your explanation makes sense. Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 2):

The following will replace all your `NA` to `"None"` strings in your `combi` dataframe.

```
combi2 <- combi %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(str_replace_na(., 'None')))
```

Comment: Or `mutate_all(funs(coalesce(., 'None'))`.

Comment: Thank you @Highland and Axeman -- these functions are above my beginner-programmer head, but I am sure they will make sense as I progress further! Thank you! :)